# How to write and run apex code in developer panel of salesforce?

Tags: force.com

It is not showing **New Apex Class** and Execute Command as shown below . Then where i have to write apex code and the execute them.
see the images ...below

[image: **Missing Apex Class and Apex Trigger to enter apex code.**]

[image: **Missing Open Execute Anonymous Window**]

Comment: Not able to see the images. could you paste it over them here instead of URl's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Check whether the edition of Salesforce you are using supports Apex or not

if your edition supports Apex.....

This might be an issue with your profile you might not be having author apex permission

in the Setup go to Manage users your username and check the profile you are assigned with and edit it if necessary...

Author apex permission will be under Administrative permissions of a profile as shown below[image]...

This is where you can find profile you are assigned with..
[image]

Comment: see the profile you are assigned to and click it you can find it on profile detail page...

Comment: @AmitAgrawal i have enhanced the answer highlighting where to find the profile assigned to you...if this doesn't solve your problem revert back for further help...

Comment: @AmitAgrawal check your email for Verification Code and send it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12154/discussion-between-sravan-alaparthi-and-amit-agrawal)

Comment: "Administrative Permissions" now appears to be "System Permissions" - at least in my version of Salesforce (Enterprise).